# req.sessionID always different except when called from localhost?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, session, express, sails.js

I got several question about sessions/connect/mongodb
Basically I'm just trying to share sessions between 2 aps, A and B, both are node apps (one is using sails).Consider that app B is not mine and I'm trying to keep the forking to a minimum.
App B does create a session in mongodb that I can access in app A. 
Consider sails session aren't persistent so I can't just req.session.user=x;
Session looks like this:

```
{
"_id" : "4kNVEPafQYN89gqlQgLXrJJKgWmJuDrr",
"session" : "{\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":1209600000,\"expires\":\"2015-08-20T22:21:22.489Z\",\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"},\"passport\":{\"user\":1},\"flash\":{},\"csrfSecret\":\"UbLpj7k3y4nT8MJOFbV2KKw3\"}",
"expires" : ISODate("2015-08-20T22:21:22.489Z")
}
```

In app A I can use sails along with connect-mongo to create sessions in the database too. 
I created a simple api just containing `console.log(req.sessionID);`
But I get a new ID every time I call it, except if I navigate first to localhost:1337 (which is app A) and after that navigate to the api route
Why is that? I don't understand why the ID is always different

Comment: How do you call app A before using localhost:1337 ? Postman or something like this ?

Comment: I've tried using postman, chrome, firefox. It's always the same result. ID is different every time. Except if I browse to :1337 before

Comment: I guess it is related to the session cookie. The cookie seems to be set only when you browse to the homepage. You can verify it comparing the response headers of the requests. How does the URL you use to call your API look like? When you are trying with chrome and firefox, are you using AJAX? If yes, what is the URL of the page sending the AJAX request? It could be a CORS problem.